# Need help making a portfolio gallery

Tags: html, css

so im building my portfolio webpage and after fooling around with my gallery i decided that with my knowledge limited to html/css, i would't be able to make a great gallery yet. so i decided to take a look around the web to find something i liked,but i didn't find anything that fitted my needs except a picasa plugin..

i found this picasa gallery plugin, which looks really great, and is responsive, which for me is a must: http://galleria.io/themes/folio/

But before buying it i wanted to ask you if you knew a great way to make something like this so heres a list of need for my gallery.

Gallery needs:
 - I want it to be simple tiles side by side, same size.
 - I want them to be clickable to view bigger versions, like lightbox.
 - Be responsive.

Any good suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at using http://masonry.desandro.com ? It has what you're looking for and it's free to use. Also the link you have just comes with a blank screen, they have JS error on their page.